# Table function for each record in a query

Tags: sql-server, function, multiple-select, table-functions

I have a function that has two outputs ...

```
dbo.func1(@code) -> Table(out1, out2)
```

This function is too costly and takes much time to calculate these two outputs.
and I have a query like this :

```
SELECT code, name,
(SELECT out1 dbo.func1(code)), (SELECT out2 dbo.func1(code))
FROM MyInnerJoinedTablesResult
```

But my costly function is call for two time but I want to call it one time for each record selected in my table... and result in two column in any row (not double rows)

```
SELECT code, name,
(out1 in func1), (out2 in func2)
FROM MyInnerJoinedTablesResult
```

Comment: `SELECT t.code, f.out1, f.out2 FROM dbo.table AS t CROSS APPLY dbo.func1(t.code) AS f`

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what you try to accomplish. Maybe some sample would help.

Comment: And make sure your table valued function is an inline table valued function. That means there is 1 and ONLY 1 statement in the function. If you have variables and all sort of processing your performance is not going to be any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Cross Apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)

```
SELECT code, name, func.out1, func.out2
FROM MyInnerJoinedTablesResult
cross apply dbo.func1(code) as func
```